# Angular JS , Tomcat Apache , # Urls

Tags: java, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I think i am dreaming in my worst nightmare with tomcat apache.

**What i want**

In angularJs there is # problem like

`www.example.com/#/aboutus`

to make this correct i read a lot, and i found that

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

can solve this and it solved my problem but after refresh the same link it says `404 not found` again i read a lots of stuff about it and i found it can be solve through **".htaccess"**

Now i was like WTF.

Because tomcat apache cant use or process  ".htaccess" files, already i have gone through this and i know it.

Now i am really cluess what to do with AngularJS in Tomcat apache,
is there any GOD/experieced/a good person/programmer who can help me?

is there anyone who have faced the same problem and used AngularJs with Tomcat Apache? and solved the # problem? (to be specific - i am using tomcat apache because my backed code is in Spring MVC)

Comment: This might help. https://jhipster.github.io/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html

Answer (score 0):

From starting and step to step so solve this head hammer problem

**Activate HTML 5 Mode**

Open the app.js file and add this line in config method:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true });
```

Then open index.html and add this line in head tag:

```
<base href="/">
```

**Note** in base href you should give your root folder otherwise it will always be redirected to localhost:/ (ex   `<base href="/cms/">` )

in your case i beleive you have done the both but you are getting the snappy 404

But here is the main solution

in **Restcontroller** try this

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
```

---

Reference : https://jhipster.github.io/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html